# Error "miss client id" Is Reported when trying to integrate Huawei AppGallery APM SDK

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, apm, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I have tried to setup the APM SDK however when I try to run my application I get the following error message:

> I/com.huawei.agc.apms: failed to fetch remote config: client token
> request miss client id, please check whether the
> 'agconnect-services.json' is configured correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0203417432150160006 which talks about this error.

I found that I had missed the (Rather important) step of actually applying the required plugin in my app level **build.gradle** file

Adding:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.huawei.agconnect'
    id 'com.huawei.agconnect.apms'

}
```

fixed the issue